# Many-to-many tag filter query with a junction table get slower with more tags. Can it be faster?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7, self-join, query-performance

### Part 1

I have this query to find some videos containing all given tags. Here with tags 1,9,27,13,67 as an example.

```
SELECT *
FROM video v
WHERE v.id IN (
    SELECT tr1.vid as video_id FROM (SELECT video_id vid FROM tag_rel WHERE tag_id=1) tr1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT video_id vid FROM tag_rel WHERE tag_id=9) tr2 USING (vid)
    INNER JOIN (SELECT video_id vid FROM tag_rel WHERE tag_id=27) tr3 USING (vid)
    INNER JOIN (SELECT video_id vid FROM tag_rel WHERE tag_id=13) tr4 USING (vid)
    INNER JOIN (SELECT video_id vid FROM tag_rel WHERE tag_id=67) tr5 USING (vid)
    -- more joins if more tags -- 
)
AND is_x=0
AND is_y=0
AND deleted IS NULL
LIMIT 0, 60
```

It executes in ~1.6 seconds.

If I run the inner select alone, it executes in ~0.8 seconds, and the result is 77 video ids.

Now, if I replace the inner select with these (example) video ids:

```
SELECT *
FROM video v
WHERE v.id IN (
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77
)
AND is_x=0
AND is_y=0
AND deleted IS NULL
LIMIT 0, 60
```

This query executes in **~0.06** seconds.

*Question 1: Why is this the case, and why doesn't the full query run in ~0.86 seconds, which is the sum of the two operations (`get video ids by tags` and `get videos by video ids`)?*

### Part 2

For my application, I can't inject the ids because the inner select might return millions of ids. So I need them in one query, together with the support of checking is_x, is_y and deleted, and offsetting the limit for pagination.

I have spent months going back and forth, and this is the fastest query for most cases.

*Question 2: Can this whole query be done faster/better with other techniques?*

*Question 3: By adding more tags, the query gets drastically slower, but isn't more joins just filtering down the number of possible results for the engine, so it should be faster with more tags?*

**Info**

tag_rel contains about half a billion rows with about .5 million unique tag ids. The video table has around 30 million rows.

Full query explain:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type   | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref                           | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tag_rel | NULL       | ref    | tag_id,video_id          | tag_id  | 4       | const                         | 1847596 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tag_rel | NULL       | eq_ref | tag_id,video_id          | tag_id  | 8       | const,db.tag_rel.video_id     |       1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tag_rel | NULL       | eq_ref | tag_id,video_id          | tag_id  | 8       | const,db.tag_rel.video_id     |       1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tag_rel | NULL       | eq_ref | tag_id,video_id          | tag_id  | 8       | const,db.tag_rel.video_id     |       1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tag_rel | NULL       | eq_ref | tag_id,video_id          | tag_id  | 8       | const,db.tag_rel.video_id     |       1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v       | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,is_x_2,deleted   | PRIMARY | 4       | db.tag_rel.video_id           |       1 |    50.00 | Using where |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Indexes:

```
tag_rel.tag_id      = unique(tag_id, video_id)
tag_rel.video_id    = unique(video_id, tag_id)
video.is_x_2        = (is_x, is_y, deleted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's compare your two queries in part 1. Assume you have 100 videos and 10 tags evenly distributed. Every:

```
SELECT video_id vid FROM tag_rel WHERE tag_id=...
```

then produces 10 rows. If you join n of those the amount of rows that have to be examined is 10^n. In your example, n is 5 so 100000 rows. The result is then filtered down to whatever amount of videos that have all those tags, and compared with the videos that satisfy the other predicates. This comparison once again multiplies the numbers of rows that have to be compared.

For second query it is sufficient to examine 1000 rows given the assumptions above. This is of course greatly simplified but should give you an idea of the amount of extra work that has to be done in the first case.

What you want to do is to find the videos that have all tags, i.e.:

FORALL x:p(x)

FORALL is the universal quantifier (see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)). Unfortenate, there is no operator in SQL that directly implements this. One way to overcome this is to translate it to an existential quantifier:

FORALL x:p(x) <=> NOT EXISTS x:NOT p(x)

This can be implemented in SQL, however most people find it more intuitive to count the distinct number of tags per movie and compare it to the length of tag list. Your query would then become:

```
SELECT video_id vid 
FROM tag_rel 
WHERE tag_id in (1,9,27,13,67)
GROUP BY video_id
HAVING COUNT(tag_id) = 5 -- 5 is the number of tags
```

Now we can simply join this back with videos:

```
SELECT v.* -- dont use * in your code
FROM video v
JOIN (
    SELECT video_id vid 
    FROM tag_rel 
    WHERE tag_id in (1,9,27,13,67)
    GROUP BY video_id
    HAVING COUNT(tag_id) = 5 -- 5 is the number of tags
) t
    ON t.video_id = v.video_id
WHERE is_x=0
  AND is_y=0
  AND deleted IS NULL;
```

The list of tags can easily be replaced by a select.

Apparently this question is not as efficient as the original, but I'll still add a possible optimization:

```
SELECT v.* -- dont use * in your code
FROM video v
JOIN (
    SELECT video_id vid 
    FROM tag_rel 
    WHERE tag_id in (1,9,27,13,67)
    GROUP BY video_id
    HAVING COUNT(tag_id) = 5 -- 5 is the number of tags
    LIMIT 0, 60
) t
    ON t.video_id = v.video_id
WHERE is_x=0
  AND is_y=0
  AND deleted IS NULL
LIMIT 0, 60;
```

Comment: Your proposed query executes in ~30 seconds compared to my ~1.6 seconds for the same result, so it's not really usable. However, your explaination for part 1 made immediate sense to me, so thank you.

Comment: What is the time for the inner query?

Comment: ~25 seconds for the inner query.

Comment: Oh, I see now that there's a limit in your query. What happens if you add limit to the inner query?

Comment: Still ~25 s with the limit. I believe I've tried GROUP BY..HAVING before without any luck. More ideas? I'm also not sure at all if I can expect to get a faster query than with my solution. But it seems like there's always a faster option in regards to SQL.

Comment: An index on `tag_rel (video_id, tag_id)` is likely to be used and help this query. But I'd expect - with a big `tag_rel` table - that the multiple joins version to (most often) be more efficient.

Comment: ypercubeᵀᴹ, that index exists already: tag_rel.video_id    = unique(video_id, tag_id). I see also that I misread the "For my application, I can't inject the ids because the inner select might return millions of ids", I interpreted it as millions of tags.

Comment: yes, I noticed the indexes after answering and commenting!

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why the subqueries are doubly nested. That combined with the   `x IN <subquery>` structure - which is known to be not well optimized in older versions of MySQL - is probably the issue. Even though you use 5.7, where there have been improvements on the optimizer, I'd prefer a `JOIN` over an `IN (SELECT ..)`, especially if the `SELECT` is quite complex.

Suggestion: try to rewrite without any subqueries / derived tables.

```
SELECT v.*
FROM video AS v
   JOIN tag_rel AS tr1 
     ON tr1.tag_id = 1  AND tr1.video_id = v.id
   JOIN tag_rel AS tr2 
     ON tr2.tag_id = 9  AND tr2.video_id = v.id
   JOIN tag_rel AS tr3 
     ON tr3.tag_id = 27 AND tr3.video_id = v.id
   JOIN tag_rel AS tr4 
     ON tr4.tag_id = 13 AND tr4.video_id = v.id
   JOIN tag_rel AS tr5 
     ON tr5.tag_id = 67 AND tr5.video_id = v.id
    -- more joins if more tags -- 
WHERE
    v.is_x = 0
AND v.is_y = 0
AND v.deleted IS NULL
LIMIT 60 ;
```

Add indexes (no need, it seems you already have these):

- a (unique) index on `tag_rel (tag_id, video_id)`
- an index on `video (deleted, is_x, is_y, id)`

Comment: You are completely right on the double nesting, I can't explain that. Though, after running some tests, your query runs exactly the same as mine so I guess the optimizer takes care of that. Yours is a lot cleaner though, so I'll swap to that. Do you think it's possible to optimize this query further?

Comment: Curious: how many rows are returned, if you remove the `LIMIT`?

Comment: Seems like the `is_x_2` index isn't used. I'll post a slightly different suggestion.

Comment: I don't have all the data on dev, so I tested on the prod server (yolo) with some similar queries: 5 tags: 0.4 seconds with limit. 5 tags: 0.2 seconds without limit, 7200 results. 7 tags: 1.3 seconds without limit, 400 results. A single random popular tag: 0.007 seconds without limit, 6.7 million results.

Comment: Thnx. Would these values (number of rows) change significantly if you removed the video conditions (`AND is_x=0
AND is_y=0
AND deleted IS NULL`) but kept the other query as above, without LIMIT ?

Comment: Yes, with my current example data without limits: with where: 0.68, without where: 0.53. I also noticed that when the query has a single tag (one join), explain shows "Using index condition", if more tags, it becomes "Using where".

Answer (score 0):

Without an `ORDER BY`, the 60 rows chosen is somewhat arbitrary.  Is that OK?

Here comes another approach.  First see if this gives you a list of ids that match tag_rel:

```
SELECT  video_id
    FROM  tag_rel
    WHERE  tag_id IN (1, 9, 27, 13, 67)
    GROUP BY  video_id
    HAVING  COUNT(*) = 5   -- 5 elements in the IN list
```

Then do

```
SELECT  v.*
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  video_id
            FROM  tag_rel
            WHERE  tag_id IN (1, 9, 27, 13, 67)
            GROUP BY  video_id
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 5 
        ) AS x
    JOIN  video AS v  ON v.id = x.video_id
    WHERE  v.is_x = 0
      AND  v.is_y = 0
      AND  v.deleted IS NULL
    LIMIT  60 ;
```

Indexes:

```
tag_rel:  (tag_id, video_id)
video:  PRIMARY KEY(id) -- I assume you have this
```